# Unable to process binding "bootstrapSwitchOn: function (){return Exclude }"

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am making an ajax call and loading the data to `ko.observablearray([])` call `self.AllMedia;` Then array is loaded I am doing for each of media. When I am doing binding **`ko.applyBindings(self);`** I am getting an error stating:

```
knockout-3.4.0.js:72 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return AllMedia }"
Message: Unable to process binding "bootstrapSwitchOn: function (){return Exclude }"
Message: valueBinding.value is not a function
```

Html:

```
<div id="draggablePanelList" data-bind="foreach: AllMedia">
    <div class="col-sm-3 list-unstyled">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                    <label @*for="IsDisabled0"*@ class="control-label">Disabled</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="IsDisabled0" data-bind="bootstrapSwitchOn: { value: Exclude, options: {size: 'mini'}}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Viewmodel:

```
self.load = function() {
  self.service.getProductDetail(self.Id(), self.populate);
}
self.populate = function(data) {
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, "", self);
  self.loadSubProductsandMedia(data.SubProducts);
}
self.loadSubProductsandMedia = function(data) {
  self.AllMedia.removeAll();
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    for (var a = 0; a < data[j].Media.length; a++) {
      self.AllMedia.push(data[j].Media[a]);
    }
  }
}
  ko.applyBindings(self);

ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapSwitchOn = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var valueBinding = valueAccessor();

    var options = {
        state: valueBinding.value(),
        size: null,
        animate: true,
        disabled: false,
        readonly: false,
        indeterminate: false,
        inverse: false,
        radioAllOff: false,
        onColor: 'primary',
        offColor: 'default',
        onText: 'ON',
        offText: 'OFF',
        labelText: '&nbsp;',
        handleWidth: 'auto',
        labelWidth: 'auto',
        baseClass: 'bootstrap-switch',
        wrapperClass: 'wrapper',
        onInit: function(event, state) { },
        onSwitchChange: function (event, state) { }
    };

    ko.utils.extend(options, valueBinding.options);

    $(element).bootstrapSwitch(options);
    $(element).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (e, data) {
        valueBinding.value(data);
    }); // Update the model when changed.
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var vStatus = $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state');
    var vmStatus = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor().value);
    if (vStatus !== vmStatus) {
        $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state', vmStatus);
    }
}
```

};

Comment: Can you show your view model code??

Comment: self.load = function () {
        self.service.getProductDetail(self.Id(), self.populate);
    }
    self.populate = function (data) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, "", self);
        self.loadSubProductsandMedia(data.SubProducts);
        self.loadedData(true);
ko.applyBindings(self);
    } 
    self.loadSubProductsandMedia = function (data) {
        self.AllMedia.removeAll();
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            for (var a = 0; a < data[j].Media.length; a++) {
                self.AllMedia.push(data[j].Media[a]);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Up next: show us which custom binding you are using, and the format of the object in `data[j].Media[a]` (the object that should have an `Exclude` property)

Comment: I am new to knockout , what do you mean by custom binding?
[
    "SubProducts": [
      {
        "Media": [
          {
            "Id": 0,
            "Path": "string",
            "Exclude": true,
            "Default": true,
            "Height": 0,
            "Width": 0,
            "Sort": 0,
            "MediaType": "Image",
            "SubProductId": 0
          }
        ]
     }
]

Comment: Please don't post code into the comments. This is completely unreadable, uneditable, in short: useless. Edit your question and add relevant code there. And while you are at it, simplify your code. Remove all the bits that do not contribute to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like the `value` property on `valueBinding`, is not a function/observable.

`var options = {
        state: valueBinding.value(),
        ...
}`

 `{ value: Exclude, options: {size: 'mini'}` is being passed into the binding, so `value` is just a reference to `Exclude` on the object that is being pushed on the `AllMedia` observable array, i.e. `self.AllMedia.push(data[j].Media[a])`.

If `Exclude` is not a function/observable, then it should be accessed as just `valueBinding.value`.  If you don't know if it is an observable or not, you can use `ko.unwrap(valueBinding.value)` to safely get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer was easy, it was because of the push that i was doing 
**self.AllMedia.push(data[j].Media[a]);**
self.AllMedia is an observable array and the elements in the Array needs to be functions to make the switch workable.

**Solution:**

```
var media = {
                    Id: ko.observable(data[j].Media[a].Id),
                    Default: ko.observable(data[j].Media[a].Default)}
```

and then push media